# Summing a decimal field using Linq to datatable

Tags: c#, linq, sum, linq-to-entities, decimal

I was able to get this to work after much frustration, but I was hoping someone could explain to me why this works:

```
var monthCharges = WRVUData.AsEnumerable()
                               .Where(dr => dr.Field<DateTime>("Posting_Month") == new DateTime(month.Year, i, 1))
                               .Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Report_Producer_Name") == provider || dr.Field<string>("Group_Name") == group)
                               .Where(dr => dr.Field<decimal?>("Charges") != null)
                               .Sum(dr => dr.Field<decimal>("Charges"));
```

but this doesn't:

```
var monthCharges = (from r in WRVUData.AsDataView()
                 select new
                 {
                     charges = r.Field<decimal?>("Charges"),
                     activityType = r.Field<string>("Activity_Type"),
                     postingMonth = r.Field<DateTime>("Posting_Month"),
                     provider = r.Field<string>("Report_Producer_Name"),
                     groupName = r.Field<string>("Group_Name"),
                     WRVUs = r.Field<decimal>("W_RVUs")
                 })
                                    .Where(dr => dr.postingMonth == new DateTime(month.Year, i, 1))
                                    .Where(dr => dr.provider == provider || dr.groupName == group)
                                    .Where(dr => dr.charges != null)
                                    .Sum(dr => dr.charges);
```

The second version throws a "Specified cast is not valid" error. Aren't the two basically the same thing?

Comment: You don't use "Activity_Type" or "W_RVUs" in the first version. Perhaps the data types are incorrect for those in the second?

Comment: Why are the two method calls different in the initial part of the LINQ queries? `WRVUData.AsEnumerable()` vs `WRVUData.AsDataView()`

Comment: @ChrisThompson, that was a mistake. I had the code copied so I could put in in this post. I actually did AsEnumerable both times.

Comment: This is also throwing the "Specified cast is not valid" error:

var errorCharge = monthCharges.Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Activity_Type") == "ERROR CHARGE").Where(dr => dr.Field<float?>("W_RVUs") != null).Sum(dr => Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Field<float>("W_RVUs")));

Comment: What type is Activity_Type? Is it really a string type in your dataset? Is W_RVUs really numeric?